# Better fuzzy matching performance?

Tags: python, performance, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison, difflib

I'm currently using method get_close_matches method from [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) to iterate through a list of 15,000 strings to get the closest match against another list of approx 15,000 strings:

```
a=['blah','pie','apple'...]
b=['jimbo','zomg','pie'...]

for value in a:
    difflib.get_close_matches(value,b,n=1,cutoff=.85)
```

It takes .58 seconds per value which means it will take 8,714 seconds or 145 minutes to finish the loop. Is there another library/method that might be faster or a way to improve the speed for this method? I've already tried converting both arrays to lower case, but it only resulted in a slight speed increase.

Comment: You can try to remove element from list b after match

Answer (score 9):

[`fuzzyset`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzyset/0.0.9) indexes strings by their bigrams and trigrams so it finds approximate matches in **O(log(N))** vs **O(N)** for `difflib`. For my fuzzyset of 1M+ words and word-pairs it can compute the index in about 20 seconds and find the closest match in less than a 100 ms.

Comment: hi @hobs thanks for pointing this out! `fuzzyset` is a great package but the documentation is very thin. How do you know that the performance is in `0(log(N))? Can you point me to some papers related to the algo?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ the docs page on pypi is pretty awesome now. They even show how they break the string up to create the trigram reverse index. Lookups on a properly implemented reverse index are never slower than `O(log(N))` -- but N is the # of trigrams, not strings, in this case.

Answer (score 4):

[RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz)

is the super-fast lib for fuzzy string matching. It has the same API as famous fuzzywuzzy, but times faster and MIT licensed.

Comment: Hi, any way to return the position of the match?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can build an index of the trigrams (three consecutive letters) that appear in each list.  Only check strings in `a` against strings in `b` that share a trigram.

You might want to look at the BLAST bioinformatics tool; it does approximate sequence alignments against a sequence database.

Answer (score 3):

### Benchmarks in 2022

tl;dr: [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) was fastest.

Test: Pick the best string match from 1.000.000 elements.
Tested on my old i7 notebook with 32gb RAM.

Best to worst:

1. [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) (drop-in replacement for TheFuzz): ~20ms
2. [fuzzyset2](https://github.com/alpae/fuzzyset/): ~320ms
3. [TheFuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) (ex fuzzywuzzy): ~7s

Comment: can you share the code of those benchmarks?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

https://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/

The Levenshtein Python C extension module contains functions for fast computation of - Levenshtein (edit) distance, and edit operations - string similarity - approximate median strings, and generally string averaging - string sequence and set similarity It supports both normal and Unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried few methods for fuzzy match. the best one was cosine similarity, with threshold as per your need (i kept 80% fuzzy match).