# How to apply entity name matching (rapidfuzz) at scale

Tags: python, string, match, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have one dataframe of user inputted car names which I need to match against another database of car names (millions of records) and extract the unique identifier. What's the best way of improving this matching whilst using rapidfuzz?

```
#Libraries
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, process, utils as fuzz_utils
```

```
#Data sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings_variable':['Avalon Toyota loan', 'Blazer Chevrolet', 'Blazer Chevrolety', 'Blazer Chevroletys', 'Blazer Chevroletys3', 'Suzuki Vitara sales', 'Suzuki Vita sales', 'Vauxhall Astra', 'Buick Special car', 'Ford Aerostar','beetle','aston martin']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'strings_variable2': ['Suzuki Vitara','Avalon Toyota loan co','some car','random car', 'Blazer Chevrolet', 'Vauxhall Astra X', 'Buick Special car', 'Ford Aerostar','Aston Martin Valkyrie','Volkswagen Beetle','GMC Syclone'],
                    'unique_id': ['100','101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','109','110']})
```

I already cleaned the data (strip characters, spaces, lowercase, stopwords, etc.) so any direct matches (such as *aston martin* : *Aston Martin*) should be removed and the remaining records should have differences (extra words, abbreviations, etc.) which is the reason for why I need to do fuzzy matching.

Using [this](https://python.plainenglish.io/150-5-minute-data-matching-gig-6a5c10ce75d6) tutorial I am able to recreate this code which provides successful results

```
df['Match'] = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    matches = []
    for i, r in df2.iterrows():
        score = fuzz.WRatio(row['strings_variable'], r['strings_variable2'])
        if score >= 90:
            matches.append(r['strings_variable2'])
            matches.append(r['unique_id'])
    df.at[index, 'Match'] = matches
    df[['match','unique_id']] = pd.DataFrame(df.Match.to_list(), index= df.index)
df = df.drop(columns = ['Match'])
```

| strings_variable | match | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Avalon Toyota loan | Avalon Toyota loan co | 101 |
| Blazer Chevrolet | Blazer Chevrolet | 104 |
| Blazer Chevrolety | Blazer Chevrolet | 104 |
| Blazer Chevroletys | Blazer Chevrolet | 104 |
| Blazer Chevroletys3 | Blazer Chevrolet | 104 |
| Suzuki Vitara sales | Suzuki Vitara | 100 |
| Suzuki Vita sales |  |  |
| Vauxhall Astra | Vauxhall Astra X | 105 |
| Ford Aerostar | Ford Aerostar | 107 |
| beetle | Volkswagen Beetle | 109 |

This works fine for such a small sample. The problem is that in reality I have to match 150 thousand records against a database of 8 million records so even even trying to match one single record against the 8 mil. database takes ages. What would be the most optimal way of doing this fuzzy matching?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into locality-sensitive-hashing? It can be used as a function that maps your strings into hash values, where similar strings map to the same hash value. Also, is this question relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408760/better-fuzzy-matching-performance?

Answer (score 0):

IMO remove the for loop, use one of the inbuilt pandas methods like lambda apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).